# Sporadic SocketTimeoutException in SOLR master when generating a new index

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, apr, socket-timeout-exception

I'm receiving sporadic SocketTimeoutException during the generation of a new SOLR index in the master (SOLR 4.5.0)

Documents are sent in packs of 500 and the exception usually occurs after ~1 or 2 millions documents have been added.

Here is the SOLR server side stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [was class java.net.SocketTimeoutException] null
at com.ctc.wstx.util.ExceptionUtil.throwRuntimeException(ExceptionUtil.java:18)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwLazyError(StreamScanner.java:731)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3657)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getText(BasicStreamReader.java:809)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.readDoc(XMLLoader.java:395)
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.fill(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:796)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:827)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.readBytes(ChunkedInputFilter.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.parseCRLF(ChunkedInputFilter.java:326)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.doRead(ChunkedInputFilter.java:128)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:738)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:405)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:162)
```

SOLR is running on Apache Tomcat (Version 6.0.26) and JAVA7.

Connector in tomcat server.xml is configured:

```
<Connector port="1086" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    connectionTimeout="600000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxThreads="100"
    keepAliveTimeout="5000"
    maxKeepAliveRequests="5"
    minSpareThreads="3"
    maxSpareThreads="10"
    compression="on"
    compressableMimeType="application/octet-stream,text/html,text/xml,text/plain"
/>
```

I believe the 600000 (10 mins) connectionTimeout counts also as socketTimeout for a APR connector..

Digging a bit in the [APR connector code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.coyote/com.springsource.org.apache.coyote/6.0.18/org/apache/coyote/http11/InternalAprInputBuffer.java#InternalAprInputBuffer.fill%28%29) it seems that the null message is caused by the missing string

```
throw new SocketTimeoutException(sm.getString("iib.failedread"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my own question.

The error was *almost certainly* caused by a timeout of the tomcat connector of the SOLR master.

In fact timeout value was 5000 (5 s) and since it has been set to 600000 (10 min) the error has not appeared again.

Regarding the *null* message it is probably caused by the missing configuration string in the APR code

```
throw new SocketTimeoutException(sm.getString("iib.failedread"));
```